# Is there a builtin Mathematica function to read hexadecimals in 0-9,a-f format?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a builtin Mathematica function that parses strings representing numbers in hexadecimal form, e.g. `"89ab"`?

I could use

```
FromDigits[
 ToExpression[Characters["89ab"] /. 
       Thread[CharacterRange["a", "f"] -> Range[10, 15]]], 
 16
]
```

or even

```
ToExpression["16^^" <> "89ab"]
```

but I'm sure there must be a more robust builtin function with error checking that I just cannot find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`FromDigits[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FromDigits.html) can already work with strings.

```
In[7]:= FromDigits["89ab", 16]

Out[7]= 35243
```